# Android - Encrypting Passwords

Tags: android

I have a preexisting  website which I want my android app to login too. I want the app to remember username and password after a user has logged in so they don't have to keep entering their credentials each time they go on the app. How can I store the password 100% safely?

The app will only allow users to upload images whereas the website stores paypal and card information so it's very important that if someone was to lose their phone and it happens to end up in the wrong hands they wont be able to extract their password. Would the password need to be decrypted on the other end?

Comment: Android != php. You want the app to store passwords, this doesn't matter what it is connecting to.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't store a password 100% safely.

There is a nice blog here about secure credential storage. http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/using-cryptography-to-store-credentials.html

For the password to be encrypted on the other end you would either need to use a single common master key or have some form of key exchange with the server.

Either that or decrypt the password locally and then send it via HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing login and password store only some kind of auth id, something like in `OAuth` and ask for password always when accessing PayPal / card and other private informations.

Comment: I recommend an option to revoke old OAuth tokens in case the phone gets stolen

Answer (score -1):

The better way to do this is to use **`MD5 hash`**. You can hash the password and then `unhash` it in your `.php` file when you receive the request to auth the user.

Plus, there is no problem to store a hash password in `database` (SQLite, MySQL, etc.)

Comment: Additionally, it's a good idea to "salt" the password before passing it to md5 to avoid rainbow table and brute force attacks.

Comment: Do *NOT* use MD5, use something stronger.

Comment: Hashing goes only one way, You can't unhash.

Comment: this is an example he can use other hash function.

Comment: No, hash is one-way. Sure MD5 has been cracked and it is not so difficult to reverse, but this defeats the purpose of having the password safe in the phone in case of theft as it wouldn't be really protected.